# If $abc=1$ then $\sum\limits_{cyc}^{}{\frac{1}{b(a+b)}}\ge \frac{3}{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math

> If $abc=1$ for positive $a,b,c$, then $\sum\limits_{cyc}^{}{\dfrac{1}{b(a+b)}}\ge \dfrac{3}{2}$

I have tried the following,in decreasing order of success:

1)AM-GM:$a+b+c\ge 3$ and $ab+bc+ca\ge 3$

2)Substituting $1=abc$ yields nothing

3)Substituting $a=\frac{x}{y},b=\frac{y}{z},c=\frac{z}{x}$ yields something weird

4)Rearrangement inequality on the sequences $\frac{1}{a},\frac{1}{b},\frac{1}{c}$ and $\frac{1}{a+b},\frac{1}{b+c},\frac{1}{c+a}$

5)Titu's lemma doesn't help

A little nudge in the right direction would help.

Comment: We need more questions like this $-$ this one lists all the attempts, and states them very clearly $(+1) \ \color{orange}{\bigstar}$

Comment: See also: [If $xyz=1$, prove $\frac{1}{y(x+y)}+\frac{1}{z(y+z)}+\frac{1}{x(z+x)} \geqslant \frac{3}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/937941)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**(I)** By *rearrangement inequality*:

$\displaystyle \begin{align} &\sum_{cyc} \frac{1}{b(a+b)} \ge \sum\limits_{cyc} \frac{1}{b(a+c)} \tag{1} \\ \iff & \sum_{cyc} \frac{1}{b(a+b)} \ge \sum_{cyc} \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{b(a+b)} + \frac{1}{b(a+c)}\right) = \sum_{cyc} \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{b(a+b)} + \frac{1}{c(a+b)}\right) \\ \iff & \sum_{cyc} \frac{1}{b(a+b)} \ge \frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc} \frac{b+c}{bc(a+b)} \end{align}$

By Am-Gm Inequality :

$$\sum_{cyc} \frac{b+c}{bc(a+b)} \ge 3\sqrt[3]{\prod\limits_{cyc} \frac{b+c}{bc(a+b)}} = 3$$

Thus establishing desired inequality.

*Note:* $(1)$ can be viewed as a consequence of CS as well.

$$\sum_{cyc} \left(\frac{1}{b(a+b)} - \frac{1}{b(a+c)}\right) \ge 0 \iff \sum_{cyc} \frac{c-b}{b(a+b)(a+c)} \ge 0 \\ \iff \sum_{cyc} \frac{c^2-b^2}{b} \ge 0 \iff \sum_{cyc} \frac{c^2}{b} \ge \sum_{cyc} b$$

**(II)** *Substituting* $\displaystyle a=\frac{x}{y},b=\frac{y}{z},c=\frac{z}{x}$:

The inequality required to prove becomes:

$$\sum\limits_{cyc} \frac{x^2}{z^2+xy} \ge \frac{3}{2}$$

We may rewrite LHS as $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{cyc} \frac{x^4}{x^2z^2+x^3y}$ and apply Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality:

$$\sum\limits_{cyc} \frac{x^4}{x^2z^2+x^3y} \ge \frac{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc} x^2z^2 + \sum\limits_{cyc} x^3y}$$

So it suffices to prove that: $$2(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2 \ge 3\sum\limits_{cyc} x^2z^2 + 3\sum\limits_{cyc} x^3y \\ \iff (x^4+y^4+z^4) + \sum\limits_{cyc} (x^4 + x^2y^2) \ge 3\sum\limits_{cyc} x^3y$$

This is the consequence of adding the following:

(i) The Rearrangement Inequality: $x^4+y^4+z^4 \ge x^3y+y^3z+z^3x$

(ii) The Am-Gm Inequality: $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{cyc} (x^4 + x^2y^2) \ge 2\sum\limits_{cyc} \sqrt{x^6y^2} = 2\sum\limits_{cyc} x^3y$

Comment: @Ewan,he has just divided both sdes of that inequality by $(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)$.

Comment: Nice, +1.  You can get directly by Rearrangement  $$\sum_{cyc} \frac1{b(a+b)} \ge \sum_{cyc} \frac1{b(a+c)}$$

Comment: Nice answer.However,can you explain your thought process when you figured out the solution?I can find annoyingly less motivation for the solution currently.

Comment: @Macavity,using rearrangement  provides me the motivation behind the solution too.

Comment: @rah4927 got it, thanks. I edited the post so as to able to undo my downvote

Comment: @rah4927 if you want to discuss intuitions behind the solution please do drop by [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics) sometime :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Indeed, as @Macavity pointed out, the sum $s(a,b,c)$ only has  circular symmetry. In fact it is not hard to show ( the same method as below) that if $a\le b\le c$ then 
$s(a,b,c)\le s(c,b,a)$.

Here is a method amenable to a computer algebra system. As suggested, substitute $a=u/v$, $b=v/w$, $c=w/u$. Get an equivalent inequality homogeneous of degree $6$ in $u$,$v$, $w\ge 0$

$$2 u^4 v^2-3 u^3 v^3+2 u v^5+2 u^5 w-3 u^4 v w+4 u^2 v^3 w-
3 u v^4 w+4 u^3 v w^2-\\-6 u^2 v^2 w^2+2 v^4 w^2-3 u^3 w^3+4 u v^2 w^3-3 v^3 w^3+2 u^2 w^4-3 u v w^4+2 v w^5\ge 0$$

with circular symmetry. It is enough to consider the cases $u\le v \le w$ and $u \ge v \ge w$.

In the first case, make the substitution $u=p$, $v=p+q$, $w=p+q+r$, with $p$, $q$, $r\ge 0$. One gets
$$8 p^4 q^2+18 p^3 q^3+15 p^2 q^4+6 p q^5+q^6+8 p^4 q r+31 p^3 q^2 r
+38 p^2 q^3 r+22 p q^4 r+\\+5 q^5 r+8 p^4 r^2+41 p^3 q r^2
+66 p^2 q^2 r^2+46 p q^3 r^2+13 q^4 r^2+14 p^3 r^3+43 p^2 q r^3+\\
+43 p q^2 r^3+17 q^3 r^3+9 p^2 r^4+17 p q r^4+10 q^2 r^4+2 p r^5+2 q r^5$$

clearly positive, with equality when $q=r=0$, that is, the $a$,$b$,$c$ are equal.
The other case is treated similarly, giving the positive expression
$$8 p^4 q^2+18 p^3 q^3+15 p^2 q^4+6 p q^5+q^6+8 p^4 q r+23 p^3 q^2 r+22 p^2 q^3 r+8 p q^4 r+q^5 r+8 p^4 r^2+33 p^3 q r^2+42 p^2 q^2 r^2+18 p q^3 r^2+3 q^4 r^2+14 p^3 r^3+35 p^2 q r^3+23 p q^2 r^3+5 q^3 r^3+9 p^2 r^4+11 p q r^4+2 q^2 r^4+2 p r^5$$

Comment: Can you please tell me what you mean by circular symmetry?Can you elaborate on the hint?I find it unclear.

Comment: the expression $s(a,b,c)$ is unchanged under circular permutations of $a$, $b$,$c$, that is $s(a,b,c) = s(b,c,a) = s(c,a,b)$

Comment: For three numbers on the circle with an orientation, either the largest is in front of the smallest one, or the smallest one is in front of the largest one. Hence, for expression in $u$, $v$, $w$ with a circular symmetry, it is enough to assume $u\le u \le w$ or $u\ge v \ge w$. If $u \le v \le w$, let $u=p$, $q=v-u$, $r= w-v$, all positive. Express $u$, $v$, $w$ in terms of $p$, $q$, $r$ and substitute. It so happens that we get an expression in $p$, $q$, $r$ with positive coefficients and thus positive.

Answer (score -1):

Look at $\frac{1}{b(a+b)}$ and $\frac{1}{a(a+b)}$. Adding together yields $\frac{1}{ab}$. So the sum is just 
$$\frac{1}{ab} + \frac{1}{bc} + \frac{1}{ac} = \frac{a + b + c}{abc}$$
The denominator is 1 and the numerator is at least 3 by AM-GM for positive $a,b,c$.

Comment: That would show that one among $\sum_{cyc} \dfrac1{b(a+b)}$ or $\sum_{cyc} \dfrac1{a(a+b)}$ is at least $\frac32$, it does not assure both should be!

Comment: Ah I was confused about the cyclic sum.

Answer (score -1):

I think the inequality is false. Currently I am searching for a triplet which disproves it. But here is my argument-
Substitute $a=x/y....$. Now write your expression in terms of $x,y,z$ and then apply Titu's lemma. You should get $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^2}{xy+z^2}\geq\frac{(x+y+z)^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2+xy+yz+zx}.$$ This means after opening it and making it greater than $1/2$, you get a positive quantity less than $0$. Not possible right. Please tell me if I am wrong anywhere and also please edit this answer(I don't know what is wrong in my syntax).

Comment: Not sure what you mean when you say greater than $1/2$, it should be greater than $3/2$.  Further even if you get that to be negative, it just shows Titu's lemma in that form is not perhaps strong enough to prove the inequality, it does not disprove the inequality :(

Comment: @orangeskid Check http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~steele/Publications/Books/CSMC/New%20Problems/CSNewProof/CauchySchwarzInequalityProof.pdf  Titu's lemma is a particular form of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: @Macavity: Oh, I see, thanks for the pointer. What about the book Cauchy-Schwarz master class? Oh, it's by the same author! Wow, neat.